# JavaScript RegExp match with flag both 's' and 'g'

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a regex in a text which contains line breaks and whitespaces on JavaScript. Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var text = $('.main').text();
  var output = $('.output');
 
  var regex = /\*\*\*.*?\*\*\*.*?\*\-\*\*.*?\*\*\*/g;
  var matches = regex.exec(text);
  var i = 0;
  
  while (result = regex.exec(text)) {
    console.log(result);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <p>***{{1}}:Meaning***<br />
  ***{{2}}:Yep***<br />
  ***{{2}}:True***<br />
  <br />
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  <br />
  <br />
  *-**{{2}}:True***<br />
  *-**{{2}}:Yep***<br />
  *-**{{1}}:Meaning***<br />
  <br />
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
```

But with the `'g'` flag it doesn't return the matches. I can get the matches with `'s'` because of line breaks.

I'm trying to get the expression between `***{{1}}:Meaning***` and `*-**{{1}}:Meaning***`. Firstly I used `match()` function, but it return only first match which is between `***{{1}}:Meaning***` and `*-**{{2}}:True***`. Then searched for it and find the `exec()` function which iterates.

I don't know how can I get the appropriate match. Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/sundowatch/pen/LYPORRO).

**EDIT**

I'm editing, because it's hard and takes time to understrand the codes above.

My regex is:

```
/qqq.*?qqq.*?qwq.*?qqq/s
```

And text is:

```
qqqLOREMqqq
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet epictetus
    qqqANOTHERLOREMqqq
        Something something something
    qwqANOTHERLOREMqqq
    consectetur epilis
qwqLOREMqqq
Etiam ut felis molestie, tempor leo sit amet, pellentesque lorem. Sed consequat ut dui et mollis. Nulla sagittis vel felis id viverra.
```

I want to get the text between `qqqLOREMqqq` and `qwqLOREMqqq`, but it takes `qqqLOREMqqq` and `qwqANOTHERLOREMqqq`.

Comment: I had hard time understanding your problem. Could you (1) simplify the examples, removing all the lots of asterisks that you use as placeholders, since it's just noise (2) avoid interacting with the DOM, since it's not useful at all here (let alone JQuery) (3) show us what's the expected result

Comment: No need to use `s`, use `[^]` to match any char.

Comment: Ok, added the edit